# How can I ask for clarification on an edit with possible issue?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

I'm not really familiar with the process but I had one of my answers edited and I think the change *might* cause a problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032215/identityserver-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-pr/32788265#32788265) had step 5 changed so now, I believe, the certificate is moved and not just copied. Not sure but moving it might have side effects?  Which is why I gave the instruction that I did, but now the edit removes that.

So basically, is it possible to comment on or ask the editors or approvers about clarifying this?

Comment: The odd thing is that same editor left a comment that "it worked". (Never minding that it's a "Compliment which does not add new information ("+1, great answer!")", http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can comment on the answer, and @mention the editor.

Meanwhile I reverted the edit. It doesn't matter if it "fixed" the answer or not. If the answer was broken, the user should've mentioned that in a comment.